# pysimplegui pass data object within multiple functions

Tags: pysimplegui

How to pass model like data objects between multiple functions & controls in pysimplegui.
Rather than coding & passing manually between the functions as arguments if there is a place holder where we can store the data objects and access them in the code it may be a clean way of code. Please let me know any suggestions.
Thanks
Sai

Comment: Try Python `class` with multiple functions.

Comment: Jason Not sure if i was clear but looking for a way to pass data or model object across multiple forms or tabs or widgets using psg...